# Get business monthend values from Pandas data frame with daily data

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to Python and I have a dataframe which I have created from a query against Postgresql database via the read_sql function in Pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, parse_dates={'asof_date'},index_col=    ['asof_date']).
```

The data that comes back has three columns and they are daily data like this:

```
asof_date       id        data_value
2013-01-02      xxx       15.6
2013-01-03      xxx       15.9
2013-01-04      xxx       15.3
....
2015-06-29      xxx       14.075
2015-06-30      xxx       15.00
```

Now, I am trying to resample this data so that only the business monthend values come back, and if I do this:

```
df.resample('BM')
```

the ID(non-numeric) column drops off automatically, and if I restack the id column back as some other questions posted suggest, it gives me an error. I have been trying different combinations as suggested by various posts and still no luck. I will appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you want to do with your ID column? It drops out as you can't aggregate strings. Do you want to take the last one or something?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use for this problem is to `pivot` the table so you only have the date as an index. This will allow the `resample` function to work.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='asofdate',columns='id').resample('BM').stack().reset_index()
```

You can then `stack` the `dataframe` and reset the index to put the field `id` back as a column.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

After playing around with this, I think I found the solution for my question along similar lines as what JAB suggests.

I will first do a groupby using the column id:

```
grouped_by_id = df.groupby('id')
```

After this, I will apply the resample method, and then use the reset_index() method to get back a DataFrame that looks more or less what I have before:

```
resampled_data=grouped_by_id.resample('BM').reset_index()
```